# Can there be a 1.1 approximation algorithm for the load balancing problem?

Tags: algorithms, approximation

I know this is a very specific question, but: Let's assume that someone designed a 1.1 approximation algorithm for the load balancing problem involving exactly 2 machines. After running the algorithm on a set of n activities, the final loads are 80 for the first machine and 120 for the second one. Is this possible given that:

a) the aforementioned job set only contained jobs with a load less than 100?

b) the aforementioned job set only contained jobs with a load less than 10?

This is taken from a set of exercises given by my uni professor as preparation for the final exam.

Comment: Unclear what you call a "load time". Both statements can be true, take all "load times" equal to $1$.

Comment: Yep, I see why it was unclear. I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: @asparagus Please tell us, what you tried by yourself. We want to see some effort.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it understandable.

Comment: We're not looking for posts that consist solely of the statement of an exercise-style task. We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.